# How to I undo a mount that was done for running docker-compose

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was initially facing an error running docker containers using docker-compose on Linux:
`Error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted`

So I followed this thread : [docker compose: Error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57796839/docker-compose-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libz-so-1-failed-to-map-s) and ran the command:
`mount /tmp -o remount,exec` on my host.

The containers started running then but after a few days it has hit a memory issues and the containers are restarting/not behaving correctly, example elasticsearch container logs:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 16785604608 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# logs/hs_err_pid316.log
error:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000003d7800000, 16785604608, 0) failed; error=‘Not enough space’ (errno=12)
```

I've tried `umount /tmp` and restarting the containers with no success. Any lead on what can I do to make this work?

Output of **df -H** when containers are running:

````
Filesystem                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                                  17G  4.1k   17G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                    108G  324k  108G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                     17G  1.4G   16G   9% /run
tmpfs                                     17G     0   17G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rg-root-lb_root              5.2G  3.5G  1.5G  71% /
/dev/vda1                                500M  169M  301M  36% /boot
/dev/mapper/rg-root-lb_aps                98M  4.1M   86M   5% /aps
/dev/mapper/rg-root-lb_opt               2.1G  239M  1.7G  13% /opt
/dev/mapper/rg-root-lb_aps_lpp_halo      252M  2.3M  233M   1% /aps/lpp/halo
/dev/mapper/rg-root-lb_aps_global        252M  4.5M  230M   2% /aps/global
/dev/vdc                                 541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps
/dev/mapper/rg-root-lb_splunk            4.2G  407M  3.6G  11% /aps/app/splunkd
/dev/mapper/rg-root-lb_home               98M  1.9M   89M   3% /home
/dev/mapper/rg-root-lb_var               4.1G  1.5G  2.5G  38% /var
/dev/mapper/rg-root-lb_var_opt           2.1G  177M  1.8G  10% /var/opt
/dev/mapper/rg-root-lb_var_log_audit     1.1G  2.9M  950M   1% /var/log/audit
/dev/mapper/rg-root-lb_var_tmp           2.1G  7.6M  2.0G   1% /var/tmp
tmpfs                                    269M   33k  269M   1% /home/local
/dev/mapper/rg-root-lb_aps_lpp_itoadmin  504M   31M  448M   7% /aps/lpp/itoadmin
tmpfs                                    3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                                    3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /run/user/418
tmpfs                                    3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /run/user/180819
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/0751962f18128ab8763e0bd123a02a74c429608e353383f6bdffafad96425856/merged
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/480ab3ebc1a887546f5ce440452c3fd8a25a4435a2f995189cbae4a275d49643/merged
shm                                       68M     0   68M   0% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/e3ea86398182213733c5954f6d83a2e63e0930700de7eebcd86997afa12d939f/mounts/shm
shm                                       68M     0   68M   0% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/1c31136f1e4862a9b5c815d7eb92a77074cedb6829a80dcef467458dee6b48ea/mounts/shm
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/2790fe99cf6318374f89b0c5a4ed12ed3bfadc02a8c6371dfcfb8298efa977d4/merged
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/9446421a2e19957104835432b8ab7bb9a123630f269ee0fdcd6beebf6caea451/merged
shm                                       68M     0   68M   0% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/9258971e17863626b7b6a1bd7113161674eb37381377071d90dff3e11f512fe2/mounts/shm
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/05d614076460494a1b1fb4a74f114de9a242bce87ccff2017188b7e3abedc043/merged
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/a41ecf88081ce5290191da8f654b733e6a4cb8d4a804a0d05ae5391e621a42ae/merged
shm                                      1.1G   62k  1.1G   1% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/a5505af5b800b25e0522e1c39e8baa826b274f30f120e7e511642b89deeb0358/mounts/shm
shm                                       68M     0   68M   0% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/78a3fa8aa9dd1dda13c6875b823a96981ba0731e77d61d102886efe95b641b57/mounts/shm
shm                                       68M     0   68M   0% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/c20704f8a2c9e21ba8e619feeed5426f717d82fbc0d48eb401d7556d8577bb6b/mounts/shm
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/0be97804429172b1cd28d50e18d34dc2386d4e2a3c55f139b08b12a3c8c9d714/merged
shm                                       68M     0   68M   0% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/fec9a398c81b544346076cdf36f0b90061af2cecf82208eb40b6d641d8a1f86c/mounts/shm
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/409a60c225aadfaf91b13a2e9218a39154eab09b72c80cb587e90b1032bfe3c9/merged
shm                                       68M     0   68M   0% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/5a720116bf074b5818b3c8db3402d58d7a7152c4144bef6af526efa1cc6adbb0/mounts/shm
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/8b21bd450e468391ba0c9897821fc797e726d109c319c9a99649232a404392ff/merged
shm                                       68M     0   68M   0% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/881b0c0a78868575f452669390939dd01f24c56f360d4bca406542b93860bac6/mounts/shm
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/f1f10b921f3524d13c868c6057e3c25ec23e510bc0c4acb50f00874f59a8e9f8/merged
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/6d7db22e59c760536ad1105fa8591d279ccf63993507cc24277d09bd83380fd0/merged
shm                                       68M     0   68M   0% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/1c29d4b600577735be7a5c9c1e3020cfc83d5619f4b2aec5e43635fc28073e11/mounts/shm
shm                                       68M     0   68M   0% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/5b9d4ea6b4e8f217f7658e54af7dad7c334a08d36da1bea6b2e95e79702e6e96/mounts/shm
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/cc7a8d6fa459ee15b17a6aa2580ea80993cec3985c0b6ce3afac712c5cfa0f39/merged
overlay                                  541G  264G  250G  52% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/overlay2/ad7b53221f10779a3e8c97397e0ea546ebef5c1dd2fe7f27063ca5691ec74aec/merged
shm                                       68M     0   68M   0% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/8b927072cc50880d8870133b5a31a26b15b679a59af9aa8ca82220aadcfd8c3d/mounts/shm
shm                                       68M     0   68M   0% /aps/app/new-apps/docker/containers/f72631c52541dc116e3cf2a0340dd3b52a1bbe92d13ee74a0798298d21e60a69/mounts/shm```
````

Answer (score 0):

The error states that there is insufficient memory (RAM). This happens because java tries to use more memory than it has been allocated. Try to allocate it more ram, if you gave it like 1 gb, try giving it 2 gb or more as needed.

If you check your ram and see you don't have enough consider limiting the ram on your other containers or get more ram.

Reference: a google search gave this result https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-insufficient-memory-for-the-java-runtime-environment-to-continue/255084